# How long does Perfmon take to write a data collector file?

Tags: perfmon

I have started a user defined data collection set with Perfmon and would like to run it for some days. It's now been almost 24 hours and the .blg file is still zero bytes. Before starting this, we tested a few times and the file was zero until the Perfmon job was stopped. Then it wrote data, we were able to open it and see the graphs.

Just want to know if this is normal. It would be a bit upsetting to let the current job run for a few days, and then when we stop it, to find the .blg file still empty.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Is this along the lines of what your looking for, sounds like the buffer isn't flushing? Circular logging https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2248192-how-do-i-ensure-that-perfmon-isn-t-going-to-harm-performance

Comment: @RichardTylerMiles I had seen those options but didn't know how to set them without first seeing how much was logged. That article is helpful as it indicates that stopping the job will write the data. I stopped it because over 24 hours have passed, and it wrote 3200KB which is not much. I'm tracking a few very targeted counters, so maybe the buffering threshold just isn't reached. I'll use those settings to see if I can make it write files more frequently. Go ahead and post as a reply, I will accept unless someone adds a definitive answer about buffering. Thank you.